# Zend_OpenId_Consumer login function hangs - even in the sample code

Tags: php, zend-framework, openid

I've been trying to get a simple OpenId log-in working using first php-openId (Jain) and then the ZendFramework, and in both cases I run up against a similar problem. I'm using the example Zend code from step 38.2.2 of http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.openid.consumer.html.

I see the log-in page fine, but when I enter my openId, this code executes:
    if (isset($_POST['openid_action']) &&
        $_POST['openid_action'] == "login" &&
        !empty($_POST['openid_identifier'])) {

```
    echo "New consumer";
    $consumer = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer();
    echo "Gotim";

    if (!$consumer->login($_POST['openid_identifier'])) {
        $status = "OpenID login failed.";
        echo "Failure";
    }
    echo "Continuing";
```

The code seemingly hangs on the function call to $consumer->login. I see the output from my first two echos, but I never see either Failure or Continuing (and without the echos I just get a 500 Server Internal Error when I try to log-in). If I enter an invalid openId then I get the correct "OpenID login failed." error message.

I apologize if I'm being a moron here. I'm a former programmer who got promoted to management, and I'm trying to get back into it - but I'm using a bunch of technologies that are new to me (PHP, OpenID, Zend Framework), and this just isn't making any sense right now.

Does anyone have any ideas where to look? I can't believe that the Framework itself is bugged (especially not when I had a similar problem with the Jain openId stuff also). I'm using fatcow.com for web hosting - not sure if that's relevant.

Comment: Check your server logs! They may/will provide some additional error information.

Comment: I've checked, and unfortunately there aren't any error logs produced by this call.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be failing when trying to make the external HTTP connection to the OpenID provider. This could be caused by a number of things, but here's a couple suggestions:

- Perhaps you're behind a proxy?
- If not that, maybe your current host does not allow contacting remote servers using sockets (the `url_fopen` ini directive). The default adapter for `Zend_Http_Client` is its socket adapter.

So, I would recommend trying is to pass a `Zend_Http_Client` instance using a different adapter to your `Zend_OpenId_Consumer` class using the `setHttpClient` method.

There are a couple different [client adapters](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.adapters.html) available:

- `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket`   (default)
- `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy`
- `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Test`
- `Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Curl`

Try something like this:

```
 $client = new Zend_Http_Client(null, array(
    'adapter'    => 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Proxy',
    'proxy_host' => 'example.com',
    'proxy_port' => 8000,
    'proxy_user' => 'user',
    'proxy_pass' => 'pass'
));

$consumer = new Zend_OpenId_Consumer();
$consumer->setHttpClient($client);
```

Your ISP should have documentation about their proxy, if this is in fact the issue.
If proxying is not your problem, try the `curl` adapter and see if you have any more luck.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't really understand what's wrong, but I tried running the same code on a different web host (x10hosting.com) and my sample code worked immediately. Therefore I have to conclude that this is some kind of limitation of the Fatcow webhosting service, which is rather a shame. I guess I'll be changing hosts.

Comment: I'd play around with different `Zend_Http_Client` (which the OpenID Consumer class uses internally) adapters, to see if you have any more luck with them. See my answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183276/1201864#1201864

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a 500 error, there is definitely a more detailed message in the web server logs. If your server is running apache, then it is most likely under /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log or /etc/httpd/logs/error_log or something similar. I am assuming you are on a shared hosting plan, so you won't have access to these. You should contact your webhosting company, as they will be able to look through the logs for you.